# Annotation @DateTimeFormat not working with Spring boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, thymeleaf, date-formatting

I am using Springboot, Java, and Thymeleaf.

```
public class DirectBind {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private LocalDate policyTermDateStart;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
 ...
}
```

My date is coming out yyyy-mm-dd. Do you know how I can change this/where to implement the code so it changes. Does it go in my controller? This is my code for when I send the form that's grabbing the user input for date

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send")
public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value = "directBind") DirectBind directBind) {
    List<String> businessAgencyList = directBind.getBusinessAgencyList();
    List<String> billTypeOptions = directBind.getBillTypeOptions();
    Mail mail = new Mail();
    mail.setFrom("no-reply@hgitservices.com");
    mail.setTo(new String[]{"stacief@hgitservices.com"});
    mail.setSubject("Oli Affiliate - AMS360 & PMA Data Checklist");
    Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<>();
    mail.setModel(mailModel);
    try {
        emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, directBind);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ("redirect:/?sentMessageFail");
    }
    return ("redirect:/?sentMessage");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/email")
public String email() {
    return "emailMessage";
}
```

Comment: Spring or Spring boot?

Comment: Sorry, Springboot.

Comment: Also if you have two questions you should ask them as two separate questions. So as the title suggests I think the main question is the latter and the one with **date range** should be in separate question.

Comment: @DateTimeFormat will the request params and will convert from string "12/02/2012" to a LocalDate object. When you are saying "date is coming out yyyy-mm-dd", are you referring to the received email? The problem may be related to the way your emails service serializes the date.

Comment: Yes I am later emailing the data to myself. It could be the email service serialization. Hmm..

Comment: So did you try to annotate class `DirectBind` with `@JsonFormat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using #temporals!

```html
<tr class="emailRow">
        <td colspan="1" class="dateRangeEnd" th:text="${#temporals.format(directBind.policyTermDateEnd, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}">
         </td>
</tr>
```